# Can't refresh access token of Google OAuth2 with refresh token even the access token is valid

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

My application get access token and refresh token via `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` API.
The response contains `access_token`, `expires_in`, `refresh_token`.
I can call gmail API with the access token, for example `GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile` API.

But I can't refresh the access token with the refresh token.

Request

```
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
  client_id: <client_id>,
  client_secret: <client_secret>,
  grant_type: "refresh_token",
  refresh_token: <refresh_token>
}
```

Response

```
{
  error: "unauthorized_client",
  error_description: "Unauthorized"
}
```

It's weird that the access token is valid but the refresh token is invalid from the same response.

And this problem doesn't happen for every google accounts.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the conditions below "Refresh token expiration" on https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 applies in your case?

Comment: @RonaldKorze the error message for a refresh token expiration is Invalid_token not aunauthorzed_client.

Answer (score 0):

unauthorized_client can mean a couple of things.  Your client id and client secret don't match.  Or the client id and client secret you are using were not the client id and client secret that was used to create the refresh token.

However i can see another issue and that is the way you are passing the data to the post call.  You should be stringing them together like a http parms with an & between them.

```
curl -s \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXXX&refresh_token=XXX&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

[How to get a Google access token with CURL.](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-get-a-google-access-token-with-curl/)